# Arquivo make file para entrar em pastas

Tags: c#, c, makefile

I have a MakeFile file in the following way:

```
conf:
    cd teste
    nano teste
```

However, when i execute `make conf`, he does not enter in the directory that i specified. How can i access different directories with makefile?

Comment: Please write in english here. In addition provide what you´ve tried and where **speciically** you´re stuck. This in particular includes providing the smallest possible code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is written in Portugese and is more likely to be on-topic at https://pt.stackoverflow.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each command in a makefile recipe acts in its own sub-shell. The first command begins in the working directory, enters `teste/` and dies; the second command begins in the working directory, and fails.

Here is one solution:

```
conf:
    cd teste; nano teste
```

Comment: With a recent enough GNU Make, you could also use a `.ONESHELL:` directive.